# How do you hide usernames in Minecraft:PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to play hide and seek with my sister in Minecraft: Pocket Edition. I don't know how to turn the gamertags off. Can you please help me?

Comment: I don't think there's a feature that allows this, so there isn't really a good way to play hide and seek. However, MCPE is still being updated, so it might be implemented in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can turn the names off, but you can leave your name slot blank or just put a "space". You can also crouch and sneak by double tapping the middle button on the control pad.

Answer (score 1):

As said above it is impossible right now (but should be if teams are made available). However, you can wear armour and give yourself infinite invisibility (/effect NAME invisibility 9999 1 true) to be able to see where the other person is, but also to hide the nametag. It's what me and my brother do on hide and seek maps!

Comment: You could also use `/effect @a invisibility 1000000 0 true`. The one you had suggested wouldn't work as you need to specify the players and the only level of invisibility is 0, because 0 is level 1. Also, the maximum amount of time is 1000000 (one million).

Comment: I was an idiot, and when specifying the name, I used the arrow symbols (whatever their called), resulting in some weird coding thing which prevented it from being seen. Thanks for alerting me! Also, I've just tested it and level 1 still works, and I think max time has been updated since I answered, but thank you for your advice anyway.

Comment: As a response to cherryblossom, nope. I know this is extremely old but ever since the `/effect` command was added it doesn't matter the amplifier for invisibility.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible, as for right now. But Minecraft could add it in the future so just wait! ^^ :)

Answer (score -2):

Its possible, Just change your name into any emoji.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot as of yet because PE is still be updating, the best you can really do is crouch

Comment: you can crouch in PE? how?

Comment: @ydobonebi double tap the crouch button

Answer (score -3):

Crouch, and leave your name blank. Best you can do.